# VirtualBox/VMWare Fusion w/ Macboon Pro M1Pro chip

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, vmware

I am dying for help here. I have read forums on here, on Oracle site, several other dev sites and I just can't seem to get anywhere. I see so many places that VB 7.0 Beta can now support Apple's M1pro silcon chips, but I have tried a half a dozen ISOs, OVAs, vmdks, and always get errors and aborted machines.

I am studying for PenTest+ and trying to add VMs like Metasplotable2/3, DVWA, Labtainers, even tried the most recent Fedora/Ubuntu/Kali ISO and no luck. I even tried VMWare Fusion (free version for home use) and still no luck. Has anyone had luck with any of the free virtualization options?

Comment: Welcome to SU. Please have a look at the [question guidelines](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1778199/edit) your question to add a bit more context. To get help for errors please add the exact error messages. Without those it's not possible to guess what might be going wrong.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Parallels supports Apple M1  ........   https://www.parallels.com/ca/pd/general/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=pd-dd-all-paidads&utm_id=645354639&utm_content=115431934459&utm_term=parallels%20apple%20m1&gclid=Cj0KCQjwxMmhBhDJARIsANFGOSt_KXUykAx96sAZa_9XGNcsSlMU25UiNOv5CW65ayrA_yyIANZEqF8aAsWsEALw_wcB

Comment: You need emulation, not virtualization since there's no x86 hardware on M1 MacBooks.  QEMU or UTM should work, but everything will be slow due to the overhead of emulating a different CPU architecture.   Parallels only supports M1 based OSes, so it won't help run Windows unless you've got the ARM version.

Comment: VB beta support virtualization but you still need to use OS images that supports the ARM architecture, not x86 or x86_64.